# RegExp - How to check for both parentheses in the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to know how can I match text ONLY if there are both parentheses (starting and closing).

Currently, my RegExp is: `^1?\s?\(?\d{3}\)?[-\s]?\d{3}[-\s]?\d{4}$`.

It checks for US valid numbers, however `\(?` and `\)?` makes the difference. It should match the text if there is 0 of them or 2.

---

Some tests:

*1 555)555-5555* - **false**

*555)-555-5555* - **false**

*(555-555-5555* - **false**

Now, they all return the same result - **true**.

---

Here is the link to it:
https://regexr.com/3kjei (`^` is because I have to select only one string without any line break, please remove 2 other strings from it so you can see it returns true. All of the strings in this link should return **true**, just check it so only one string is in the text editor).

Thank you

Comment: The straight line solution would be something like `\(\d{3}\)|\d{3}`.

Comment: No, it has to select full string. Please, don't change my RegExp, everything is OK, I only need to check for both parentheses.

Comment: Try [`^(?:1\s?)?(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})[-\s]?\d{3}[-\s]?\d{4}$`](https://regex101.com/r/RGJ3Ww/2). Note that `^1?\s?` in your regex allow a single whitespace in the beginning, that is why I suggest `^(?:1\s?)?` - an optional sequence starting with `1` that is optionally followed wih whitespace.

Comment: If you want the behaviour of your regex to be different, then you're going to need to change it.

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew, it works.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth The problem I'm doing this for a challenge and it has many checks, so yours would make them wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?:1\s?)?(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})[-\s]?\d{3}[-\s]?\d{4}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RGJ3Ww/2).

Note that `^1?\s?` in your regex allow a single whitespace in the beginning, that is why I suggest `^(?:1\s?)?` - an optional sequence starting with `1` that is optionally followed wih whitespace.

The `\(?\d{3}\)?` part is replaced with `(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})` - a [non-capturing  group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) that matches either `(`+3 digits+`)` or 3 digits (so, no `(123` or 123)` can be matched).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:1\s?)?` - 1 or 0 occurrences of `1` optionally followed with 1 whitespace char
- `(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})`  - either `(`, 3 digits, `)` or just 3 digits
- `[-\s]?` - an optional `-` or whitespace
- `\d{3}` - 3 digits
- `[-\s]?`- an optional `-` or whitespace
- `\d{4}` - 4 digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: What can I say, you are really pro at this thing :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not in the portion of your regex that says `\(?\d{3}\)?` that you "or" it instead.
Eg. Replace it with something like this:

`((\(\d{3}\))|\d{3})`

Comment: It's the same as @Wiktor's answer. And it has some improvements. Thank you for your time, but I'll accept his answer :)